# How can I overlay a background color over an NSVisualEffectView and use vibrant controls?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsvisualeffectview

I want to use `NSVisualEffectView` with dark vibrancy, but I find the effect too pale in some situations, so I'd like to darken the background.

Here is an example app, using `NSBox` views to provide a darker background.

[image]

We can see that the `NSBox` 'primary' appearance manages to overlay the background and the button happily sits on top of that. However, on the `NSBox` with custom appearance, the button appears to 'cut' through the background to the visual effect view beneath.

I've tried subclassing `NSVisualEffectView` and overriding `-drawRect:` to fill it with a different color and the result is the same.

Is there a way to overlay vibrant controls over other views?

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Effect View seems to have two important layers: Backdrop and Tint. Setting both of these to the "right" black seems to do the trick, but you'll need to do this anytime the bounds change.

```
for (CALayer *sublayer in self.vibrancyView.layer.sublayers) {
    if ([sublayer.name isEqualToString:@"Backdrop"]) {
        NSLog(@"Backdrop: %@", sublayer.backgroundColor);
        sublayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.45].CGColor;
    } else if ([sublayer.name isEqualToString:@"Tint"]) {
        NSLog(@"Tint: %@", sublayer.backgroundColor);
        sublayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. Are you doing within-window blending or behind-window blending?

Comment: Within-window. Using the same technique, are you able to log the sublayers of an empty visual effect view to see what's available to play with?

Comment: Ah. I need behind-window blending. But I did try logging the layers in `setFrame:` and `setBounds:` on the NSView, there was nothing there. I guess they were set up after the layout pass.

Comment: Apparently behind window blur is done by the window server, so maybe you have no control over that. Maybe adding a black layer with a plusL/plusD compositing filter (log the Tint layer's compositing filter from a within window view for an example) to the visual effect view might work?

Comment: Checking the compositing filter on an allows vibrancy view gives the following, which leads me to think you can just say `layer.compositingFilter = @"plusL"`;

`(lldb) po commandView.layer
<CALayer:0x630000022300; position = CGPoint (10 0); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 80 36); contents = nil; compositingFilter = plusL; opacity = 0.5; anchorPoint = CGPoint (0 0); NS_view = <TimelineCommandView: 0x630000120500>>
(lldb) po commandView.layer.compositingFilter
plusL
(lldb) po [commandView.layer.compositingFilter class]
__NSCFConstantString`